# Update information at specific timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'll try to explain my question the best way I can.
I'm not asking for codes, only for the best method of doing it.

I want to create a browser game and use time for upgrading stuff, building etc.

For example, to build 1 house will take 1 hour.

So I will began with saving the `timestamp+(60*60)` at the moment the user did his action.

My question is, how to update it the best way?

One way I thought of was to add function that check every page view of the user if it's done.
But then if he's not logged in the update wont happen.

Second way i thought about is for every page view of any user to check for every user registered. But it's not effective and there is a problem if no user is logged in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about a scheduled cron job?

Comment: You can always use crons, though, you'd have to have a cron running every minute if you have a lot of players, so I am not sure if it's efficient. It could work better than having each page load check it manually.

Comment: Take a look to NodeJS if you want to use real-time applications.

Comment: I thought about it as well. But it really uneffiecient and it would work every 1 min, I need it to work every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my game doing it simply, without crons.
When a player wanted something that takes time, i just updated his database information with the appropriate time of ending that job (columns are just examples)

```
UPDATE player SET jobend = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + (60*60*4)   # ending in 4 hours
```

Then, every page that had an information about the remaining time, i just used something like this:

```
SELECT (jobend - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) AS jobremaining FROM player
```

I formatted correctly the time using [strftime](http://php.net/strftime) and i displayed that to the user.
In the case the remaining time was negative, the job was done.
There was no-need for absolute counting since user was able to do something with the job when he was connected.

When the player just changed pages or doing something else i had a function where i just checked all timely events while the user was online (so to catch any negative timer), then presented with javascript any change (i posted javascript counters for every page)

Now, if you talk about updating in real-time, **cron** is the way but are you sure you're going to need it for a game? I asked that question myself too and the answer was not.

**EDIT**

If another player sees the `buildings on schedule` page (an hypothetical page) i am doing the same calculations; if a time just got negative for a specific player (regardless if another player see the page), i just reward him with the building (in database i make all the changes), even if he's *offline*. There's no harm in this, since he can't do anything anyway. The other players will just see he has a building. The key here is that i execute the required updating PHP code *regardless* of player's connection to the game; as long at least ONE player is logged-in i'm executing the progress function for everything.
This isn't so slow as it sounds (updating all players by using just a connected player that visits a specific page). You just have a table of 'jobs' and check timers against the current time. More like a single query of getting the negative ones.

Comment: Thank you, but what happen when the user isn't logged in? If a user build house for example, I want other user to see if the house is built even if the user never logged in again.

Comment: Glad you asked that question i missed :) Check my edit